# PostgreSQL function always returns: "cannot execute CREATE FUNCTION is a read-only transaction"

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, kernel, readonly

I can't execute a function using PostgreSQL 9.4. It always returns:
"Kernel error: cannot execute CREATE FUNCTION is a read-only transaction"
How could I change that? I never specify READONLY in my code.

Example of function I tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION less_than(a TEXT, b TEXT) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
    local_a text := a;
    local_b text := b;
BEGIN
    RETURN local_a < local_b;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you connecting?

Comment: I'm using Heroku, could it explain my problem?

Comment: Are you using psql for connection?

Comment: What *application* are you using to connect and run the SQL? Also, is there any chance you're connecting to a read-replica ("follower" in heroku-speak)?

Comment: Thanks Craig, yes I am on a follower DB, which must be the problem.